# Follow post plugins for WordPress

Tags: plugins

I'm running a Q&A site with wordpress. I am wondering if there is any plugins that add a "follow" button at the end of a post like Quora such that users can follow the post or follow the topic.

Thank you.

**Example page with follow button:**
http://www.quora.com/Is-Quora-planning-an-API

Comment: I am not familiar with Quora, could you please write out what exactly that button should do?

Comment: Quora is a Q&A site, they show a Follow button on the question pages, i've added a link Jin's question.

Answer (score 2):

This plugin "allows commenters to sign up for e-mail notifications of subsequent replies."

[Subscribe To Comments Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/)

Answer (score 1):

ok, could this be a solution for you? This is a plugin like the wordpress.com button that lets your users follow your blog. I think you can do some setup here to follow by category etc.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/follow/